# Matlab - a command to sort variables into groups and output the group indices

Tags: matlab, sorting, vector, matrix

I have a vector, for example: a = [1 1 2 2 7 7 7 10 10 10 10 11 15]. It can be unsorted, but here I'm writing it as sorted. I am looking for a Matlab command that will convert the above to [1 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 6]. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least two ways to do this

(1) use the third output of `unique`:

```
[~,~,out] = unique(a)
```

(2) use `grp2idx` from the statistics toolbox

```
out = grp2idx(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do the conversion with only one command, but this is one way to do it:

```
a = [1 1 2 2 7 7 7 10 10 10 10 11 15];

a = sort(a);
UniqVector = unique(a);
for i = 1:size(UniqVector, 2)
    a(a == UniqVector(i)) = i;
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this but was looking for a single command to do it. I knew such command must exist...